# How to close the windows installer setup wizard after launching the application. VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a desktop application that needs to be installed in my clients pc. I am able to launch the application when the installation is complete. The issue is once the application is launched, the setup wizard is still open and the client needs to press the "Close" button to exit setup. I am wondering if there is a custom action that I can use to close the setup window automatically after the application is launched?